# Retrieve Twitter usernames in a bot that executes Twitter "POST statuses/update" in response to specific keywords

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, automation, bots

Building a Twitter bot to:

1. search for tweets with keywords like "Net Neutrality"
2. Return the tweet IDs and usernames for those tweets
3. Publish a tweet in response to that user (via **in_reply_to_status_id**, as described in [Twitter Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update))

Here is my current code:

---

```
const Twitter = new twit(config);

let tweet = function() {
    let params = {
        q: '#netneutrality, #savethenet, Net Neutrality',
        result_type: 'mixed',
        lang: 'en'
    }

    // search through all tweets using our params and execute a function:
Twitter.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data) {
        // if there is no error
        if (!err) {
           // loop through the first 4 returned tweets
          for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            // iterate through those first four defining a rtId that is equal to the value of each of those tweets' ids
          let rtId = data.statuses[i].id_str;
          let username = data.statuses[i].username;
            // the post action
          Twitter.post('statuses/update', {
            // setting the id equal to the rtId variable
            in_reply_to_status_id: rtId
            , status: `@${username} Send single-click #SaveTheNet tweets to key politicians at fliplist.app.  Take 60 seconds to protect our Internet, once and for all.`
            // log response and log error
          }, function(err, response) {
            if (response) {
              console.log('Successfully tweeted');
            }
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
        }
      }
        else {
            // catch all log if the search could not be executed
          console.log('Could not search tweets.');
        }
    });
}

tweet();
setInterval(tweet, 600000);
```

---

When I ran it, there was a successful output ("Succesfully tweeted" 4 times in terminal), and there were indeed 4 new tweets published from my account.

However, the username in all of those tweets was @undefined.

So I imagine I'm either failing to collect those usernames from the relevant tweets or failing to add them to the status string appropriately.

Any suggestions for how I can fix this?

For reference, here is a link to one of the @undefined tweets: https://twitter.com/ProoveTweets/status/1075855455958765569

And a screenshot is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqGiO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note.  Firstly, Twitter's usernames are called "Screen Names".  So you code should probably read:

```
let username = data.statuses[i].user.screen_name;
```

Take a look at the search documentation for an example of the JSON being returned. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Secondly - please don't do this! Automatically replying to keywords is against the developer terms of service and is *really* annoying to users.

https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation